# How to how all files with either of two file extensions in JFileChooser OpenDialog

Tags: java, jfilechooser

The user will choose a file in JFileChooser that will be converted to a new file format and then saved with a different extension.  I'd like to display files with both extensions so that the user will be able to see if the file has already been converted.

I've been able to add two FileNameExtensionFilter methods but that means that the user must toggle between them.  Is there a way of filtering out all but the two extensions?  The alternative appears to not use a filter and accept all files.  (In the distant past I was able to do this in Windows using C/C++)

I'm using Java under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a custom filter:

```
fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if( checkForFileTypeOne() ||  checkForFileTypeTwo()) {
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return "Usefull files (*.abc, *.def)";
    }
});
```

Comment: I had to add:  f.isDirectory()  to the logic.  Works just as I wanted, thanks.

Comment: It may also be useful to remove the ability of the user to select the default filter which accepts any file extension:  `fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getAcceptAllFileFilter());`

Answer (score 0):

just make the `FileFilter` accept either file type

```
 public boolean accept(File f) {
      if( /* File is first type */ || /* File is second type */)
          return true;
      return false;
 }
```